# JS associative array from form input field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My form contains multiple input fields. For example:

```
<input type="number" class="attribute-class form-control"  id="Size" min="1" max="99999" name="attribute[]">
<input type="number" class="attribute-class form-control"  id="weight" min="1" max="99999" name="attribute[]">
```

Now I want to create an array, something like this `array[size => 10, weight=> 20]`

Is that even possible? 
So far I used this function I found on another topic, but I get a regular array with just the fields value.

```
var attribute = $("input[name='attribute[]']").map(function(){
            return $(this).val();}).get();
```

Reason for this: I have to load additional input fields in my form with ajax, depending on what type of product the user selects, and then I have to store fields name and value in database. This is the only option I could think of.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays. You can use an object, which is somewhat similar.

Comment: @j08691 That comment never gets old.

Comment: @undefined If I only had a nickel for every time I've written it...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, post edited.

Comment: What you want is an object: `{size: 10, weight: 10}`. There's a jQuery plugin that does this: [serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an object, not an array. You want to use the IDs as the property names in the object.

```js
$("#x").click(function() {
  var attribute = {};
  $("input[name='attribute[]']").each((i, input) => attribute[input.id.toLowerCase()] = input.value);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(attribute));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Size: 
<input type="number" class="attribute-class form-control" id="Size" min="1" max="99999" name="attribute[]"><br> 
Weight:
<input type="number" class="attribute-class form-control" id="weight" min="1" max="99999" name="attribute[]">
<br>
<button id="x">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to create an object to store the values from your input fields,

Maybe try something like this :

```
    var myObject = {};
    document.querySelectorAll("input[name='attribute[]']").forEach(element => {
       myObject[element.id] = element.value
    });
    console.log(myObject); // <-- this should have your values in it now.
```

JavaScript does not have associative arrays, use a JavaScript object which is very similar.